# Problems deploying WAR file from Netbeans to Tomcat

Tags: netbeans, war, web-deployment

I'm trying to configure build.xml files for build forge, but it seems like I am having trouble with the libraries required for the java servlet pages.  I am actually trying to use OWASP's AntiSamy library but I keep getting a Policy Exception followed by a file not found

> org.owasp.validator.html.PolicyException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files \Apache%20Software%20Foundation\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\XSSDemo\WEB-INF\classes\...\antisamy.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

The antisamy.xml file is definitely in this location, however.

So I tried using Netbeans to clean and build a WAR file that I would have expected to work, since the web app works fine when I run it through Netbeans.  However, I get the same problem.  Is there possible some reference that Netbeans is creating when I run the app through the ide that is not occurring in the WAR deployment?  Could the URL Encoding in the antisamy.xml location be causing problems?

Thanks for the help.

Edit:  I compressed the long class path into the three dots here.  The actual response has the actual class path.  I am not getting any kind of security errors.

Comment: Have you tried putting your XML file right in the WEB-INF/classes directory instead of putting it in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was not actually with the deployment--it was the file reference itself in my java servlet.  The encoding in the path '%20' in the Program Files folder caused a FileNotFoundException.  The reason this did not occur in netbeans is because the deployed files are in a c:\users... folder and there are no spaces to be encoded.  The also explained why the application ran well on other computers with their tomcat folders directly on the root directory.  [This is the actual solution to my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207644/how-can-i-get-the-filename-of-a-servlet-resource)  Thanks for all your help.